# Is it safe to cut a window header for pellet vent pipe?

Tags: carpentry, woodstove

I want to install a pellet stove in our sunroom. The spot where I had wanted to put it I thought would be high enough to clear any headers above the windows, but it seems that this, what I think is a header, extends about 16" above the windows. The windows in question are side by side and span about 6' along an exterior wall that runs parallel with the direction of roof rafters.

The cut I would need to make would notch out about 3" into the header to fit the pellet vent wall thimble (maybe 6" diameter).

The closer image link has a shaded area that shows what would need to be cut. This might not be a header but can't figure out what else it would be.

[image]

[image: closer image]

Comment: Why is there a header above the window at all? The load bearing wall should run along the bottom of the rafters. I would expect no header down low, but hitting a rafter up high. Can you get a tiny drill bit and poke around a bit?

Comment: That cross hatching indicates the solid wood?  Have you knocked on the wall at least to confirm that a beam runs along the whole length of the windows?

Comment: Extend the vent up 4" to clear that bit of solid wood.

Comment: Oh, and good on you for drilling some test holes to see what's back there! You may also want to use a stud finder that has wiring detection built in, just to be sure there isn't wiring back there that you may cut through. Don't know where or why there might be wiring there, but it's always a good idea to check.

Comment: @popham Where Dave found it seems like where the header would be expected to be.  Header at the top of the window rough opening with cripple studs between the header and the top plate of that wall and a rafter on top of that.  Does not surprise at all that it would be built that way.

Comment: It goes all the way across. I cut the drywall... https://imgur.com/a/VrzmUCs

Comment: And just saw the other comments because I hadn't refreshed the page. I was afraid if I go any higher I'll be too close to the celing? Manuals for vent and stove don't say anything about pipe distance from celing  though. I can drywall patch and move the hole up if I shouldn't cut the header.

Comment: Does your thimble have a big square flange, where you've been obsessing over the hole at that elevation to keep its level and plumb edges clear of the ceiling? That's been my working assumption. I'd cut that bottom plate out of the way. Just to be sure, your 6" hole accounts for all of the clearances around the thimble, right? I did a horizontally vented gas stove once and I recall a lot of complexity in those details.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory, if there is a rafter, then it and the other rafters would be carrying the loads to the rafter ends. There would be no need for a header to carry the load. A bearing wall running parallel to rafters like this is therefore unusual. The header here is massive even supposing that this was a bearing wall with that 6' opening (unless the photographer was standing on the ground floor of a 3 story home with sloped second floor). The IRC's https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7.4 provides the typical detail above this window.

Comment: The wall thimble has the square flange. It clears the celing slope and I could even move it up and it would still be level but the pipe is pre made. And twist locks together. Not sure if they make a section that's an extra three inches. Here's another picture backed up a bit. https://imgur.com/a/m3mFKWe I am thinking the rafters must run the direction the roof pitches (blue lines). Would they ever run perpendicular to the roof slope? I didn't think they would but I got up on the ladder and am getting hits every 16" on the red lines.

Comment: My gas installation nested an inner duct for hot exhaust inside an outer duct for fresh air. I think I recall seeing a telescoping section that I didn't order because it was unnecessary, but I may be confusing it with the thimble's wall thickness adjustability. Seems crazy that a manufacturer wouldn't, unless it's forbidden. I'm sure you'll do the research. On the rafters, I was thinking maybe you had a really short span the silly-seeming way and a long span the other way. Assuming there are 2-2x12s in there (1-1/2" top and bottom), that's a lot of capacity for just a roof. Interesting.

Comment: It looks like that window goes all the way to the corner but we can't see the adjacent wall.  Is there another window there?  Is it possible that there is no solid support at the corner and the header above the window is actually a cantilevered beam that's holding up the whole roof (or at least the corner of it) like an awning?  Safe advice:  if you want to cut things that may be structural, hire a structural engineer.

Comment: I don't think it's cantilevered. This was an addition done long before I owned the house. You can see in this picture the other side of the window and how they connected the walls sort of. https://imgur.com/a/psdTTPe I'm just gonna patch it and move up the hole. I think I found an adjustable section of pipe.